# how to check device is flagship android device

Tags: android, device-detection

I have a flagship android device like http://www.minix.us/products/NEOX7.html . 
It's hardware device. so i want to check in my application if device is flagship android device

Comment: I have no idea what might be at that URL -- which returns a 404 File Not Found error -- that would signify a "flagship android device". You might wish to explain yourself what a "flagship android device" is.

Comment: It seems you misunderstood what flagship means. It is a general term  to describe your main product, e.g. for samsung it is the Galaxy s4, for HTC it is the One etc.

Comment: its hardware device. its not like mobile and tablet.see this link http://www.minix.us/products/NEOX7.html

Answer (score 1):

`Build.MANUFACTURER` and `Build.MODEL` will give you some potentially useful information about the device that your code is running on.

However "flagship" is really more of a marketing term than anything else. Whether a device is "flagship" or not makes very little technical difference, so there is really no way to check this unless you have a list of which model devices you are considering to be "flagship"